# Design view disappeared from Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, interface, builder

All of a sudden, the visual design window disappeared from my Interface Builder. It is a regular UIView, has some UIImageView, UILabel, and UIButtons on it. When I open IB, I can see the document window (with File's Owner, First Responder and View in it), Library and Inspector, but the visual design window disappeared. Double click on "View" in the  document window doesn't do anything. If I go to List mode, I can see all the components on the view, but just can no longer find the visual design window. All other XIB can open just fine, only this XIB lost its design window.

First I thought maybe it was hidden somewhere on the screen. Tried all kinds of things, even rebooting the computer, but nothing helped.

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance! By the way, I'm running SDK 3.2 Beta 3.

Comment: You may have answered your own question with the "Beta 3" bit. Can you reproduce this behaviour with the latest official release?

Comment: Well, I experienced the same thing once with 3.1.3. It was never resolved and eventually I gave up and recreated the NIB and the class. Wondering if it is just something simple I missed.

Answer (score 8):

Does it show up in Exposé? Does the inspector show its properties when you double click on the view? I’m just wondering if the view’s editor window has somehow been moved offscreen.

Here’s an idea. XIB files are just XML. You should be able to open it in a text editor and change the window’s location. Search for the string “>{{”, which should match against encoded NSRects. See if you can find a rect with an origin that would put it offscreen.

Comment: You'd man! It is fixed.

It doesn't show up in expose, but inspector displays correct information.

Then made a backup of the XIB and open the file as you suggested. Sure enough, there is a {{-583,120},{320,480}} string in the file. Changed it to {{0,120},{320,480}} restarted IB and it is now there.

I have an external monitor at work. Maybe I moved the window to that monitor and expose/IB is not smart enough to bring it back to the main window when there is only one monitor.

Thanks again!

Comment: This happens when you're using an external monitor and move the IB design view on the external display. Next time you're opening the XIB file without your external monitor plugged in, the design view position is still offscreen. Todd's solution works. Look for ">{{" values which are larger than your current screen bounds or even negative and correct them.

Answer (score 5):

For whatever reason what worked for me was: double click the "View" icon, press CMD-w, double-click "View" again.

Answer (score 2):

Just right-click (or ctrl-click) at the .xib or .storyboard and choose: Open As > Interface Builder.

Answer (score 0):

very new to Xcode & interface builder - I had a similar problem and came across this page whilst searching for solutions.  I found that by going to the 'document' window and dbl clicking on the 'window' icon, brought the design view of the window back.

Answer (score 0):

Simply expand the side outline view pane if not already open (triangular arrow in a circle at the bottom left of the IB pane), then open and expand the object hierarchy and click in any one of the view objects. It will select it and center it into the view. That will miraculously make the whole view reappear. At least worked for me in Xcode 4.3.3 and Xcode 4.5.2. I certainly got scared the first time it opened on a blank view though, I thought it had lost the design. But it was just off screen with no scroll bars to get to it (in my world it's called an XCode bug).
I like Todd Yandell's solution to edit the file as a permanent fix, but it's more work...